# Fragment height not filling container

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-android-api-2

I've placed a map fragment inside a linear layout, but the problem is that for some reason the fragments takes almost the whole device height instead of taking the container's height when I test it on the emulator. The layout preview in Android Studio is perfect.

[Layout's code](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/566103cd6ab814aae027)

Preview:

[image]

Emulator:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that both of the first and the second child LinearLayouts of the parent LinearLayout should be set *layout_height="match_parent"*.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    (...)
    >

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        (...)
        >

        (...)

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        (...)
        >

        (...)

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```